# Having a problem with using RxJS to average out an array of variables in Angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have a Firestore database that has fields including: `day`, `morning`, `afternoon`, `night`, with the times of day being numeric usages during that time.
I'm trying to use this code to average out the values of `morning` etc, per day (`sunday`, `monday`, ...).

```
import { Subscriber, Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, toArray, reduce, switchMap, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

...
groupedData: any = [];
meter:Observable<any>;
meterId: string;

ngOnInit() {
this.meter = this.db.collection('meters').doc(this.meterId).collection('data').valueChanges();

  from(this.meter)
      .groupBy(x => x.day)
      .flatMap(group => group.toArray())
      .map(g => {
        return {
          day: g[2].day, 
          morning: _.sumBy(g, 'morning'), 
          afternoon: _.sumBy(g, 'afternoon'), 
          night: _.sumBy(g, 'night'), 
        }
      })
      .toArray()
      .subscribe(d => this.groupedData = d);
}
```

and I'm getting the error of `Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

I think I'm trying to adapt this from an earlier version of Angular/RxJS code, but am failing miserably. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pipe` as in the example below:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getItems() {
    this.http.get('https://example.com/api/items').pipe(map(data => {})).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

You can also chain multiple operators as:

```
getItems()
.pipe(
  switchMap(users => from(users)),
  mergeMap(user => forkJoin(getAddresses(user.id), getCompanies(user.id))
                   .pipe(map(data => ({user, addresses: data[0], companies: data[1] })))
  tap(data => data.user.addresses = data.addresses),
  tap(data => data.user.companies = data.companies),
  map(data => data.user),
  toArray()
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused how either one of these options answers my question. I need to do more than just mapping data. That I can do easily.

Comment: My point is to use the latest syntax of rxjs. Sometimes there are backward compatibility issues.